# forward min and max in time series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How to get the min and max of a time series data?
I know that the rolling gets the values from the past, however, I want to get the data for the next 3 days.

```
pip install yfinance

# data 
df=yf.download('tsla',start='2015-11-26',end='2021-4-28',interval='1d')

# df['min']=df['Close'].roling(3).min # this gives me the min of the past values is there a way of getting the min from the next three days?
```

using the shift -3 method gives me the following which does not work [image: shift -3]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.rolling()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rolling.html) with parameter `center=True`, as follows:

```
df['min'] = df['Close'].rolling(7, center=True).apply(lambda x: x[-3:].min())
```

With parameter `center=True` for [`.rolling()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rolling.html), we are looking at the cener (middle) of the window.  Now with window size set at 7 and looking at the middle of the window, we are working at both a backward window of size 3 and a forward window of size 3.  Hence, we can use `x[-3:].min()` to get the min of the last 3 entries (forward 3 entries) of window `x`.

Result:

```
print(df.head(10))

                 Open       High        Low      Close  Adj Close    Volume        min
Date                                                                                  
2015-11-25  44.268002  46.166000  44.076000  45.928001  45.928001  19954000        NaN
2015-11-27  46.212002  46.450001  45.402000  46.321999  46.321999   9747000        NaN
2015-11-30  46.358002  46.855999  45.816002  46.051998  46.051998  13299000        NaN
2015-12-01  46.212002  47.599998  46.209999  47.438000  47.438000  18670000  46.076000
2015-12-02  47.400002  47.720001  46.245998  46.397999  46.397999  14907500  46.076000
2015-12-03  47.096001  47.490002  46.000000  46.542000  46.542000  14698000  45.344002
2015-12-04  46.492001  46.653999  45.532001  46.076000  46.076000  12868000  44.903999
2015-12-07  45.540001  47.125999  45.230000  46.226002  46.226002  15721000  44.903999
2015-12-08  45.504002  45.759998  44.840000  45.344002  45.344002  13438000  43.403999
2015-12-09  45.340000  45.500000  44.144001  44.903999  44.903999  15289000  43.403999
```

### Edit

If you want to get the min of closing prices of current date plus 2 days ahead and without `NaN` values at the first few days, you can use [`numpy.fmin()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fmin.html) as follows:

```
import numpy as np

df['min'] = np.fmin(np.fmin(df['Close'].values, df['Close'].shift(-1).values), df['Close'].shift(-2).values)
```

Result:

```
print(df.head(10))

                 Open       High        Low      Close  Adj Close    Volume        min
Date                                                                                  
2015-11-25  44.268002  46.166000  44.076000  45.928001  45.928001  19954000  45.928001
2015-11-27  46.212002  46.450001  45.402000  46.321999  46.321999   9747000  46.051998
2015-11-30  46.358002  46.855999  45.816002  46.051998  46.051998  13299000  46.051998
2015-12-01  46.212002  47.599998  46.209999  47.438000  47.438000  18670000  46.397999
2015-12-02  47.400002  47.720001  46.245998  46.397999  46.397999  14907500  46.076000
2015-12-03  47.096001  47.490002  46.000000  46.542000  46.542000  14698000  46.076000
2015-12-04  46.492001  46.653999  45.532001  46.076000  46.076000  12868000  45.344002
2015-12-07  45.540001  47.125999  45.230000  46.226002  46.226002  15721000  44.903999
2015-12-08  45.504002  45.759998  44.840000  45.344002  45.344002  13438000  44.903999
2015-12-09  45.340000  45.500000  44.144001  44.903999  44.903999  15289000  43.403999
```

Comment: Just to note, this will be slow due to `.apply`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55557758/913098). Also makes little sense to roll over windows of 7 when all you need is 3

Comment: @Gulzar  Yes, I know.  But the question does not mention that system performance is critical and I used real data to test it.  It's processing is quite quick.

Comment: Running time 0.4s for data of 5.5 years.  Good enough.

Comment: I added a picture to explain what I want to do. we also should not get NaN becasue we are looking forward and the data is available.

Comment: @AMEXPO  So for 2015-11-30, you want to get the min of the Close price of the 3 dates 2015-11-30, 2015-12-01 and 2015-12-02 ?

Comment: Exactly! curren date plus two days ahead

Comment: @AMEXPO  See my edit above.  Amended as per clarified requirements.

Comment: @AMEXPO  Pleased to help!  Please remember also to upvote the solution. :-)

Comment: Sure! just did :)